# Opencart template doesn't render

Tags: php, module, opencart, opencart2.x

I just started learning OpenCart, currently using version 2.3.0.2 .

I created a module, everything works fine on the backend.

On the frontend however, when I return the template from the controller it shows up blank.

But if I add a `die();` in the template it loads the template.

Controller code:

```
    <?php
class ControllerExtensionModuleHelloworld extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->load->language('extension/module/helloworld'); 

        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['helloworld_value'] = html_entity_decode($this->config->get('helloworld_text_field')); 


        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/extension/module/helloworld.tpl')) {
          // print_r(__LINE__);
            return $this->load->view($this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/extension/module/helloworld.tpl', $data);
        } else {
          // print_r(__LINE__);
            return $this->load->view('extension/module/helloworld.tpl'); 
        }
    }
}
```

Template code:

```
 <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"> <?php echo $heading_title; ?> </div>
    <div class="panel-content" style="text-align: center;"> <?php echo $helloworld_value; ?> </div>
  <div style="height:100px;width:100px;background-color:blue;"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by changing:

```
return $this->load->view('extension/module/helloworld.tpl', $data);
```

To:

```
$this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/helloworld.tpl', $data));
```